# Difficulty in including external CSS and bootstrap files in HTML inside templates folder of flask

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I am facing difficulty in accessing CSS and bootstrap files inside HTML within localhost:5000 in flask programming.

I've already tried including the CSS files within static folder but it doesn't work.

```
<head>
<title>HOME PAGE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap.css') }}">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='homestyle.css') }}">
```

I expect all the CSS modules to be included in the HTML file without any obstacles.

Comment: add your HTML code & folder structure

Comment: did you try placing bootstrap.css first and then homestyle.css ?

Comment: Have you checked that the path to your css files is correct? it would not `static/css/homestyle.css` instead?

Comment: @VillageMonkey yea but it doesn't work

Comment: @LaljiTadhani the folder structure is templates and a static as sub folder within templates

Comment: @Suzie Your folder structure is incorrect. Check the edit in my answer.

Comment: what is web server you are using ?

Comment: if you are using nginx server, you can use send_static_file method as specified here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55350112/difficulty-in-including-external-css-and-bootstrap-files-in-html-inside-template?noredirect=1#comment97574685_55350112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='homestyle.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap.css') }}">
```

Edit: Make sure your folder structure matches the following:

```
static/
├── homestyle.css
├── bootstrap.css
templates/
├── index.html
app.py
```

The static folder should be at the root, ***not*** inside the templates folder.